# Expectation of fair die game when all but one branch cut off

Tags: expected-value, dice

> - Any roll of a 1, 2, or 3 results in the player winning the amount of the die roll, in dollars,
>   and the termination of the game.
> - Any roll of a 4 results in the player winning $2 and continuation of the game.
>
> Let Y denote the payoff in dollars of the game. Find E[Y ].

My try:
$$\begin{align}
E[X] &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(2k +\frac{1}{4} +\frac{2}{4} +\frac{3}{4}\right)\frac{1}{4^k}\\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\frac{1}{4^k} + \frac{3}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^k}\\
&= 2\frac{4}{3}\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\frac{1}{4^{k-1}}\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}\\ &= \frac{2}{3}\frac{4}{3} + 2\\
&= \frac{26}{9}.
\end{align}$$

The right answer is $\frac{8}{3}.$ What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: What happens with a roll of $5$ or $6$? Or is it just a $4$-sided die?

Comment: @paw88789 4-sided, yes, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separately count the expected payoff from all rolls of $1$, $2$, or $3$ and the expected payoff from all rolls of $4$.

For the first part we have
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac14 + \frac24 + \frac34\right)\frac{1}{4^k} = 2. $$

This part of your calculation is correct.

Alternative method: exactly one of these rolls will occur, it will be the last roll, and the last roll has equal probability ($1/3$) to be each of the three possible outcomes, so the expected payoff from these rolls is
$$\frac13 + \frac23 + \frac33 = 2.$$

For the second part, you say that if you roll $4$ exactly $k$ times before the end of the  game then the payoff from $4$s will be $2k.$

The probability to roll $4$ exactly $k$ times before the end of the game is
$$ \frac34 \cdot \frac{1}{4^k}.$$
The expected payoff therefore is
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2k \cdot \frac34 \cdot \frac{1}{4^k}. $$

You did not include the factor of $\frac34$ in your calculation.
That is how you got a result greater than the correct result.